# Java Debug Interface: put the breakpoints at arbitrary locations in the code

Tags: java, debugging, breakpoints, jdi

I am using the  [Java Debug Interface API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/index.html) to write the custom programs for debugging the Java applications I write. I am able to add breakpoints to the start of a required method invocation by using the code as:

```
ReferenceType classRef = vm.classesByName(className).get(0);
Method meth = classRef.methodsByName(methodName).get(0);
BreakpointRequest brF1 = vm.eventRequestManager().createBreakpointRequest(meth.location());
brF1.enable();
```

However I am unable to make out how to get Location objects for arbitrary locations within the source files.

Comment: Why don't you use the debugger in your IDE?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/ReferenceType.html#locationsOfLine%28int%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to retrieve a `Location` for other locations in a source file.

E. g., `Method` has several operations for this:

- `allLineLocations()` + 1 overload
- `locationsOfLine(int line)` + several overloads

Also ReferenceType has operations for this. Just browse for the usage of `Location`.

Comment: What is overloads ?